# Open, quasi-compact sets in Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

**Question**
Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with identity and $U\subseteq Spec(A)$ is open. Show that $U$ is quasi-
compact in the Zariski topology if and only if $U = Spec(A)\backslash V(I)$ for some finitely generated
generated ideal $I\subseteq A.$

**My attempt**

*Forward Direction:*

Suppose $U$ is quasi-compact. Since $U$ is open in the Zariski topology, $U = Spec(A)\backslash V(I)$ for some ideal $I\subseteq A.$ We claim that $I$ is finitely generated. Since the family of basic open sets $B=\{D(f)|f\in A\}$ forms a basis for the Zariski topology on $Spec(A),$ $U=\bigcup_{f\in S} D(f)$ for some subset $S\subseteq A.$ As $U$ is quasi-compact, this cover has a finite subcover. i.e., $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D(f_i)$ for some $f_1,...,f_n\in S.$ **I think** we need to claim that $I$ is generated by $f_1,...,f_n.$ (please correct me here if I'm wrong.) So,
$$U=Spec(A)\backslash V(I)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} D(f_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} Spec(A)\backslash V(f_i)=Spec(A)\backslash \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} V(f_i)$$
$$\Longrightarrow V(I)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} V(f_i)$$
$$\Longrightarrow \sqrt{I}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}} (f_i).$$
From here, I am not sure if this implies $I$ is generated by $f_1,...,f_n.$

*Backward Direction:*

I tried to imitate the proof of "$Spec(A)$ is quasi-compact", which I can prove. I proved this by using **a metric space X is compact if and only if for each family of closed sets with the finite intersection property have nonempty intersection.** However, I could not prove the backward direction successfully.

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: For the forward direction, you are correct in saying that $U$ being open implies $U = \operatorname{Spec} A \setminus V(I)$ for some ideal $I$, but there is a lot of freedom in this $I$. For example, we could replace $I$ with $\sqrt{I}$, and it might happen that one choice of $I$ is finitely generated while another choice is not. As a result, I would refrain from choosing $I$ at the outset. Instead, we observe that you have shown that $U = \operatorname{Spec} A \setminus V(f_1,\ldots, f_n)$ and so we can choose at the end to take $I =(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$.

Comment: @BrianShin Oh that makes sense! Thanks so much! Was my approach right for the backward direction?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of what you have for the backward direction so far. In particular, the Zariski topology usually does not come from a metric. (In fact, it can almost *never* come from a metric.) I will try to think of something more helpful to say.

Comment: @BrianShin Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the forward direction, you've got the right idea, and we've cleaned up the argument a bit in the comments.

For the backward direction, assume $U = \operatorname{Spec}A \setminus V(I)$ for $I = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ a finitely generated ideal. We make the following observation:
$$U = \operatorname{Spec} A \setminus \bigcap_{i=1}^n V(f_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\left( \operatorname{Spec} A\setminus V(f_i)\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}$$
where $A_{f_i}$ is the ring $A$ with $f_i$ inverted. (These are mostly the same observations you made above.) Now, we know each $\operatorname{Spec}A_{f_i}$ is quasi-compact (since it is affine). We have then that $U$ is a finite union of quasi-compact open subsets, and so it is itself quasi-compact. (This is a result from topology. If it doesn't sound familiar, you should try to prove it :) )

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I still have a couple of questions though. I'm new to all these stuff so could you please tell me what 'affine' means? Also why does affine imply quasi-compact?

Comment: Ah, "affine" just means "is $\operatorname{Spec}$ of some ring", and you know "$\operatorname{Spec} R$ is quasi-compact for any ring $R$"

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much!!